# Shortcode Wordpress Responsive

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to change the parameter of a shortcode in wordpress responsive. For example the shortcode is [course_list col="3"]. So there are 3 columns displayed.

From the size of 800px and less I would like to change the number of columns to 2 ([course_list col="2"]). Is there a way to change this directly in the shortcode or has this be changed in the code?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have to do this in CSS. Please add the name of the plugin in your answer and paste the HTML of the shortcode, then i can create css to make the course_list responsive

Comment: Ah okay. I could resolve it with CSS. Thank you for this clue! ;-)